# Centralizer of order $pq$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a non-trivial element $x$ of a group $G$, and let $Z(x)$ be the centralizer of $x$. Suppose that $|Z(x)|=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime. Show that $Z(x)$ is abelian.

The centralizer of an element $x \in G$ is defined as $Z(x)=${$g\in G | gx=xg$}.

My idea is to do a proof by contradiction. Suppose that $Z(x)$ is not abelian. Then, there exists some $a,b \in Z(x)$ such that $ab\neq ba$. Since $a \in Z(x)$, $axa^{-1}=x$ by definition, and similarly, $bxb^{-1}=x$. Hence, $axa^{-1}=bxb^{-1}$. Some algebraic manipulation yields that $x(a^{-1}b)=(a^{-1}b)x$.

I don't seem to be getting to a point where I would need to use the fact that $|Z(x)|=pq$, so I'm assuming that I am on the wrong track. I also have the counting formula, which says that $|G|=|Z(x)||C(x)|$, where $C(x)$ is the conjugacy class of $x$, which could possibly be useful. A push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p=q$, then $|Z(x)|=p^2$, and any group of order $p^2$ (where $p$ is prime) is abelian.

Next, suppose $p\ne q$.

Note that $x\in Z(x)$.

Since $x$ is non-trivial, we have $|x| > 1$.

If $|x| = pq$, then $Z(x) = \langle x \rangle$, so $Z(x)$ is abelian.

Then suppose $|x|= p\;$or$\;|x|=q$.

Without loss of generality, suppose $|x| = p$.

Then $Z(x)$ must contain an element $y$ of order $q$.

Since $y$ commutes with $x$, it follows that $xy$ has order $pq$.

But $xy\in Z(x)$, so $Z(x)$ is cyclic, hence abelian.

Comment: Are you using $o(x)$ to denote the order of $x$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Why does $|x|=pq$ imply that $Z(x)$ is cyclic?

Comment: Because $Z(x)$has order $pq$, and $x\in Z(x)$. Since $x\in Z(x)$, it follows that $\langle{x}\rangle \subseteq Z(x)$.